# Self hosting WCF without config - Hard time understanding setting up endpoints

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, self-hosting

I've researched this for a day now and am turning to you experts here for your advice.

I have REST service that is the main IIS hosted service.

This service needs to interface with a 32-bit unmanaged .dll.  In order to do this I'm taking one common approach which is creating a self hosted service and making calls to it.

With that background, I'm having one heck of a time getting the self hosted one working propertly.

here is the code that WORKS:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/theSvc");
            Uri mexUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/theSvc/mex");

            // Create the ServiceHost.
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ImgService), baseAddress))
            {
//                var wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
  //              wsHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
    //            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IImgService), wsHttpBinding, baseAddress);

                // Enable metadata publishing.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetUrl = mexUri;
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);



                // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
                // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
                // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
                // by the service.
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHost.
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now...if I uncomment these lines in order to increase the maxreceivedMessageSize and remove the baseAddress from the using statement, I can no longer add a reference to the service:

So change this:

```
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ImgService), baseAddress))
```

To this:

```
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ImgService)))
```

And uncomment this:

```
//                var wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
  //              wsHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
    //            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IImgService), wsHttpBinding, baseAddress);
```

The error that I receive is:

... -> local host

```
There was an error downloading 'http://...:8080/theSvc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://...:8080/theSvc'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://...:8080/theSvc'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

As like everyone else that posts here...I'm in a bind.  Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered an alternative approach to WCF, which tends to be complex to set up compared to a simple HTTP service?

Comment: I would be 100% all for that if it would suffice my needs.

I feel like I'm very close with the WCF service if I can just get this last configuration portion figured out

Comment: Well, you've been warned :) Seriously, I can't help you on that, I carefully avoid WCF

Comment: I certainly appreciate the warning.  Ultimately WCF is the way I'm going because I don't know an other way.  

If I could find another way to create some service that allows me to make a call into it from my REST service I'd definitely go that route.

Any suggestions that might help me take a different route?

Thanks Simone

Comment: Plain HTTP with either NancyFx or even plain HttpListener unless you need WCF features can be well enough.

Comment: Hmmm...ok thanks.  Ultimately the service is only returning one this...which is a base64Encoded string.  I'll look into that as an alternative as well.

In the meantime if anyone has thoughts/solutions sure apprecaite it.

Arg...why did I pick this profession :)

Comment: If all your wrapped dll needs to expose is a string you're unlikely to need WCF, which doesn't mean you cannot use it though. See if you get it to work or look into the two options I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear you are not adding the service endpoint.

This is a function I'm using to startup an http host, however I am hosting it in a windows service. Which is the same as your console application.  But IIS might think about it a bit differently.

```
static Uri scannerSvcBaseAddress;
static BasicHttpBinding scannerBinding;
static ServiceHost scannerHost;

public void startScannerWcfService(long eventID)
{
    try
    {
        db.writeServiceLog(eventID, "STARTUP", "=== Scanner WCF Service Starting ===");

        string addressToHostAt = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScannerHostBaseAddress"];

        if (addressToHostAt != null && addressToHostAt.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {

            scannerSvcBaseAddress = new Uri(addressToHostAt);
            scannerHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(BarCodeService.ScannerService), scannerSvcBaseAddress);

            //Allows publishing of METADATA to developers when self hosted on a remote system                 
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = scannerHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (smb == null)
            {
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            }
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            scannerHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            scannerHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

            scannerBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            scannerBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
            scannerBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            scannerBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            scannerBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            scannerBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            scannerBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, Global.scanUserIdleLogout * 2, 0);

            //scannerBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0, 0);

            scannerHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(BarCodeService.IScannerService), scannerBinding, "");

            var behavior = scannerHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
            behavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;


            scannerHost.Open();

            db.writeServiceLog(eventID, "STARTUP", "=== Scanner WCF Service Started ===");
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Host Base Address not provided");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        db.writeServiceLog(eventID, "STARTUP", string.Format("Error in ServiceManager.startScannerWcfService: {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
        throw;
    }

}
```

All that said, as was mentioned above if you only need to expose a string WCF may be overkill.  I'm using WCF in a windows services to connect to handheld scanners in a warehouse environment, and I am really happy with how it performs.  Though it was a huge pain to get it working initially.

But since the question was asked in the context of WCF I thought I would respond with a known to work function that does essentially what you want to do.

Comment: DING DING DING DING winner winner chicken dinner!!!

I love StackOverflow.

Thanks so much for taking the time to post that.  That seems to have fixed my problem.

Now I just need to go through line by line and understand why.